# How to write ElasticSearch Query on the basis of distinct objects?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elasticsearch-5, kibana-6

Here I am trying to get the distinct attribute name on the basis of tenant_id and hierarchy_name , this is my data which is Indexed

```
       {
      "hits": [
        {
          "_index": "emp_indexs_datas_d_v",
          "_type": "bulkindexing",
          "_id": "84",
          "_source": {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "PRODUCT",
            "values": "GEO"
          }
        },
        {
          "_index": "emp_indexs_datas_d_v",
          "_type": "bulkindexing",
          "_id": "88",
          "_source": {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "CUSTOMER",
            "values": "CUSTOMER_OPEN_1"
          }
        },
        {
          "_index": "emp_indexs_datas_d_v",
          "_type": "bulkindexing",
          "_id": "98",
          "_source": {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "PRODUCT",
            "values": "CUSTOMER_OPEN_2"
          }
        },
        {
          "_index": "emp_indexs_datas_d_v",
          "_type": "bulkindexing",
          "_id": "100",
          "_source": {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "CUSTOMER",
            "values": "CUSTOMER-ALL"
          }
        },
 {
          "_index": "emp_indexs_datas_d_v",
          "_type": "bulkindexing",
          "_id": "99",
          "_source": {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "CUSTOMER",
            "values": "CUSTOMER_OPEN_2"
          }
      ]
    }
```

This is the query which was trying here , I was getting the distinct attribute_name on the basis of hierarchy_name

```
{
        "query": {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "CUSTOMER",
                "fields": [
                    "hierarchy_name"
                ]
            }
        },
        "collapse": {
            "field": "attribute_name.keyword"
        }
    }
```

Now I want to match one more property tenant_id , previously I was matching with hierarchy_name ,can someone help me with the query

output expected . like suppose for tenant_id 2 and hierarchy_name PRODUCT we get

```
{
  "hits": [
    {
      "_index": "emp_indexs_datas_d_v",
      "_type": "bulkindexing",
      "_id": "84",
      "_source": {
        "tenant_id": "2",
        "hierarchy_name": "CUSTOMER",
        "attribute_name": "GEO"
      }
    },
    {
      "_index": "emp_indexs_datas_d_v",
      "_type": "bulkindexing",
      "_id": "98",
      "_source": {
        "tenant_id": "2",
        "hierarchy_name": "CUSTOMER",
        "attribute_name": "CUSTOMER_OPEN_2"
      }

    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could also post an example of the output you want. You should probably read up about `bool` queries in the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

Comment: expected output provided pls check @tomr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`bool/must`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) clause to combine multiple conditions

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "tenant_id": 2
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "PRODUCT",
            "fields": [
              "hierarchy_name"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "attribute_name.keyword"
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67379727",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.4144652,
        "_source": {
          "tenant_id": "2",
          "hierarchy_name": "PRODUCT",
          "attribute_name": "GEO"
        },
        "fields": {
          "attribute_name.keyword": [
            "GEO"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67379727",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1.4144652,
        "_source": {
          "tenant_id": "2",
          "hierarchy_name": "PRODUCT",
          "attribute_name": "CUSTOMER_OPEN_2"
        },
        "fields": {
          "attribute_name.keyword": [
            "CUSTOMER_OPEN_2"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: really I was waiting for your response , Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, which differs from the accepted answer in three ways:

- analyzed `match` query is replaced by non-analyzed `term` filter. Using analyzed filters can produce unexpected/surprising results (see the `match` [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#match-field-params) for explanation)
- `multi-match` query is replaced by a `term` query. Using multi-match for a single field is a bit redundant and hard to read, plus it's another analyzed query
- `collapse` is replaced with a `terms` aggregation. This is just the way I've always done it

Using a `terms` agg to get all the values of `attribute_name.keyword` means that we're limited to a certain number of results per shard. This can be gotten around by using a `composite aggregation`. I don't know whether the same concern applies to use of `collapse`, but if you have a large number of distinct values then it's probably wise to check.

The query using `term` queries and a `terms` agg:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "tenant_id": 2
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "hierarchy_name": "PRODUCT"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_attribute_names": {
      "field": "attribute_name.keyword",
      "size": 1000
  },
  "size": 0
}
```